# merging 2 sorted lists in ascending order

Tags: python, computer-science

Is there a way to merge 2 sorted lists with list1 being in ascending order and list2 being in descending order but the new merged list should be in sorted ascending order. I'm looking to do this without using any built-in functions or recursion.

I have the following but it only works if list2 is also in ascending order.

```
def merge2(list1, list2):
    results = []
    while len(list1) and len(list2):
        if list1[0] < list2[0]:
            results.append(list1.pop(0))
        else:
            results.append(list2.pop(0))
    results.extend(list1)
    results.extend(list2)
    return results
```

The function should produce the following:

```
merge2([1,3,11,34],[60,38,7,1,0]) => [0,1,1,3,7,11,34,38,60]
```

Comment: len is build it :). If you use len, you could probably use reverse as well

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the first element of `list1` and the last element of `list2` and you can `pop` from the end of `list2` with `pop()` (without any arguments). Finally, you can `append` the remaining lists in `list2` to `result` with `pop()` until there are none left.

So with a little modification, your code becomes:

```
def merge2(list1, list2):
    results = []
    while list1 and list2:
        if list1[0] < list2[-1]:
            results.append(list1.pop(0))
        else:
            results.append(list2.pop())
    results.extend(list1)
    while list2:
        results.append(list2.pop())
    return results

print(merge2([1,3,11,34], [60,38,7,1,0]))
# [0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 11, 34, 38, 60]
```

Comment: this works but as I said is there a way of actually doing this without using reversed because that is a built in function that Im trying not to use.

Comment: @CutiePie Ah, good point. You can use the same idea as in the first `while` loop (see updated answer). `pop` will remove the last element in the list so you can keep doing that until `list2` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can do basically the same thing with a `for` loop.
This means only `list2` is mutated.

```
def merge2(list1, list2):
    result = []
    for item in list1:
        while list2[-1] < item:
            result.append(list2.pop())
        result.append(item)
    while list2:
        result.append(list2.pop())
    return result
```

Note that this doesn't use `len` (which is a builtin function)